# Bypassing javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've got a text box in which users have to enter a numeric value, from 0 and greater, the validation for that field is:

```
"user.compensation":{
                    number : true,
                    greaterThan0 : false,
                    max : 99999999.99,
                    min : 0.00
                },
```

The greaterThan0 is coded as:

```
//validation for non zero decimal fields
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan0", function(value,element) {
    var formattedValue = value.replace(/\,/g, '').replace('US$','');
    return (parseFloat(formattedValue) > 0);                                        
}, "Value must be greater than zero." );
```

In some cases though, the user can save the form, without entering a value in the text box. In this instance, we want to save the value as -1. But the validation above works against this logic.

What's the cleanest/easiest way to bypass the validation for cases like this?

Comment: If `-1` is a magic number that you would input for user, shouldn't it be done in server-side instead of client-side? Your validation logic should be implemented in server-side as well.

Comment: Hi @AlexLau, but how can I bypass the validation to get to that point? I don't allow blank fields to save either.